# Checking topological equivalence in shapely

Tags: python, shapely

## Problem

I am using shapely 2.0.0. I have a bunch of polygons in shapely as `shapely.Polygon` and I would like to check if any of the polygons is a rectangle. This can be done by checking if a polygon's minimum rotated rectangle is **topologically equivalent** to itself.  I have tried the following approaches (please refer to below codes):

1. Testing if the minimum rotated rectangle is topologically equivalent to the original polygon using `shapely.equals`. However, this method fails due to floating point errors and apparently there is no way for me to use `shapely.equals` with tolerances based on the [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.equals.html?highlight=equals#shapely.equals).
2. Testing if the minimum rotated rectangle is structurally equivalent to the original polygon using `shapely.equals_exact`. [The problem is this requires the polygon's coordinates to be equal (within specified tolerance) and in the same order](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.equals_exact.html#shapely.equals_exact), which in this case the minimum rotated rectangle have different order of coordinates than the original polygon which causes problems. Moreover, in general polygons may have different number of coordinates on the exterior and still have topological equvalences.
3. My current inplementation thus check if the area of minimum rotated rectangles vs the original polygon is in certain tolerance. The problem is this is not really checking the topological equvalence and may fail for some cases.

This thus raised me a question that I would like to have your suggestions: **With the consideration of floating point operations, What is the best way to check the topological equvalence of polygons in shapely?** Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

## Minimal Reproducible Example

```
from shapely import minimum_rotated_rectangle,  Polygon
from shapely.plotting import plot_polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
box1 = Polygon([(0,0),(0.5,0),(0.5,0.8),(0.2,0.8),(0,0.8),(0,0)])
box2 = minimum_rotated_rectangle(box1)
```

```
plot_polygon(box1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plot_polygon(box2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### 1st approach (fails because of floating point error):

```
>>>box1.equals(box2)
False
>>>box1.area
0.4
>>>box2.area
0.4000000000000001
```

### 2nd approach (fails because of exterior points mismatch):

```
>>>box1.equals_exact(box2,tolerance = 1e-3)
False
>>>box1.boundary
LINESTRING (0 0, 0.5 0, 0.5 0.8, 0.2 0.8, 0 0.8, 0 0)
>>>box2.boundary
LINESTRING (0 0, 0.5 0, 0.5 0.8000000000000002, 0 0.8000000000000002, 0 0)
```

### Current approach

```
>>>import math
>>>math.isclose(box1.area,box2.area,rel_tol=1e-9)
True
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you described some of the business motivation for the use case. Where did the polygons come from, and what sources of noise perturbed them?

Comment: @J_H Well, my question is more of a general question to understand the usage of the shapely package. Nevertheless, one specific use case (and the reason why I have this question) is I am currently writing a package for CNC tool path generation based on shapely for some pixelated regions. You may consider the regions to be some write areas which may be joined from smaller, more fundamental geometries (coloured pixels); If the joined polygon has topological equivalence I may generate one tool path for all regions with topological equivalence.

Comment: So e.g. if a "side" of a big rectangle wasn't a single 90px raster, but rather was 30px, then 30px off-by-one raster, then 30px again off-by-one, it would still be "one side" since the imaging hardware may have introduced 1px noise on a side that IRL is actually a straight line. Ok. Sounds like your hardcoded `rel_tol` = Konstant is not appropriate, as the number of pixels we tolerate should be proportional to line length, no? Is this problem perhaps really about "elide points from middle of almost straight line" ?

Comment: Ooohh! This looks very nice. https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.hausdorff_distance.html It uses the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) to find the distance between two geometries. And such a distance between a 3-point "almost" line and a 2-point line will be very very small, could be a good fit for your use case. For a simpler approach, maybe compare the slope `m` of lines as you go clockwise around the shape?

Comment: @J_H An approach based on Hausdorff distance is workable if the two polygons can be superimposed on each other with coinciding centroids and the correct orientation. Fortunately, for my application, the polygons in comparison can be assumed to have the same orientation. (They may be pure translations of each other but coinciding centroids is rather trivial in shapely)

Comment: @J_H Please write a short answer so I can vote on your answer, thanks!